# Novel where the main character travels to another dimension by bus

Tags: story-identification, books

I was reading a book where the main character has just enough money for a bus fare. He and the other passenger are transported to another dimension(?) or the future(?)

The protagonist seems to have been a warrior in a past life.

Comment: When did you read this?  How is the other dimension/the future different from his home place/time?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: There is C.S. Lewis's _The Great Divorce_ where the bus goes to Heaven...

Comment: Probably not, but could it be "The Man Who Traveled in Elephants" by Heinlein? Published in his collection "The Unpleasant Profession of Jonathan Hoag". Salesman John Watts in a bus, imagining his wife Martha by his side. They end up in a parade in what may well be Heaven. Protagonist wasn't a warrior, though.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly an [Iris Wildthyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_Wildthyme) novel?  There are a lot of them, and I'm not sure I've read any of them, so I couldn't be sure which one this is if any.  Apparently she's not always from the same place or even the same literary universe in all her appearances, but in some of them she's a renegade Time Lady and drives a time travelling London bus.

Comment: In some of them, she drives a time-travelling London bus even when she's *not* a Time Lady!

Comment: Thank you for all your replies.
I don't think it is any of those listed.